# Performing side effects on Publisher

Tags: ios, swift, combine, frp

I'm trying to perform side effect on `Publisher`, and I can't find any operator which will allow me to do something like this. To be precise, I'm looking for a concept similar to RxSwift's `do(on:)`.

Here's what I'm trying to do.
I'm writing a reactive wrapper for a delegate provided by a 3rd party SDK. It's and SDK for interacting with BLE devices. I have methods like `startScanning` and `stopScanning` and what I want to achieve is to react to signals and call `stopScanning` as a side effect of any error or complete events. So far, I have something like this:

```swift
newDeviceFoundPublisher
            .timeout(.seconds(timeout), scheduler: DispatchQueue.global())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

and what I want to achieve is something like:

```swift
newDeviceFoundPublisher
            .timeout(.seconds(timeout), scheduler: DispatchQueue.global())
            .doOnError {
                manager.stopScanning()
            }
            .doOnComplete {
                manager.stopScanning()
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Is there already something like this or maybe I'm missing something, and there's something in Combine I can use and get the result?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might be looking for the `.handleEvents` operator. You can implement it with any of five different parameters; they are all optional, so implement just those you need. Both an error and a completion would count as `receiveCompletion:`.

Note that the error will still flow on down the pipeline if you don't `catch` it! (The completion will flow down the pipeline in any case, and I don't think you can stop it.)