# Swift Combine: handleEvents vs map

Tags: swift, combine

Let's assume you have a publisher that returns a list of some entity. Let's say it comes from a use case that fetches something from an api

```
protocol SomeAPI {
    func fetchSomeEntity() -> AnyPublisher<[SomeEntity], Error>
}
```

Now you want to run some side effect on the output. Say, saving the result into a repository.

You would go with the `handleEvents` operator wouldn't you.

```
    api.fetchSomeEntity().handleEvents(receiveOutput: {[unowned self] list in 
         repository.save(list) 
    })
```

But what if someone did that using/misusing the map operator:

```
api.fetchSomeEntity().map { [unowned self] list in
   repository.save(list)
   return list
}
```

Would you say there's something fundamentally wrong with that approach or is it just another path to the same end?

Comment: I would say there's something fundamentally wrong with using `map` that way, but I also think this question is over in Opinion territory.

Comment: Thanks @matt. Actually, I put that "fundamentally" qualifier in there to convey that I was not looking for opinions and personal preferences but for someone knowledgable with the implementational details of the combine pipeline who could explain to me why is it a bad practice to use side effects in this way (or in anyway, as David here argues to be the case)

Comment: Well I've given you my opinion. The job of `map` is to alter what comes down the pipeline. If what comes down the pipeline has a secondary job to do, `share` the value into a second pipeline, or use `handleEvents` as you suggested.

Comment: Thank you matt it does make sense and it is what I was thinking when I called it a misuse of map. Yours seems to be a good justification to call it as such.

Comment: But that doesn't make this a valid Stack Overflow question. There are no objective grounds on which to distinguish a "right" answer.

Comment: I can't argue with that. Like I said I was hoping for an answer that goes like: this is wrong because it impacts the performance, etc. But I ended up being convinced with ontological answers, like map is meant to transform the result and functional means no side-effects. and while they both do make perfect sense, they do fall within the realm of opinions. So if this question is a candidate for removal, I have no objection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of those operators are appropriate for your goals.

You should never do side effects in Combine pipelines, let alone executing `map` just for side effects, so calling `repository.save` inside a `map` is bad practice.

Side effects should only happen when handing back control to the imperative code from the functional Combine pipeline, so either in `sink` or in `assign`.

`handleEvents` on the other hand should only be used for debugging, not for production code as the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/receiving-and-handling-events-with-combine) clearly state.

> Use `handleEvents(receiveSubscription:receiveOutput:receiveCompletion:receiveCancel:receiveRequest:)` when you want to examine elements as they progress through the stages of the publisher’s lifecycle.

The appropriate method you are looking for is `sink`. `sink` is the method to use when you want to execute side effects when a combine pipeline emits a value or completes. This is the method for handing back control to the iterative part of your code after the reactive pipeline.

```
api.fetchSomeEntity().sink(receiveCompletion: { 
    // handle errors here
}, receiveValue: { [unowned self] list in 
    repository.save(list) 
}).store(in: &subscriptions)
```

If you want to do something like data caching in the middle of your pipeline, the way to do it is to break your pipeline. You can do this by doing the caching separately and updating an `@Published` property when the fetching succeeds, then observe that property from your view model and react to the property changing rather than the fetch succeeding.

```
class DataProvider {

    @Published var entities: [SomeEntity] = []

    func fetchAndCacheEntity() {
        // you can replace this with `repository.save`, the main point is to update an `@Published` property
        api.fetchSomeEntity().catch { _ in [] }.assign(to: &$entities)
    }
}
```

Then in your viewModel, start the Combine pipeline on `$entities` rather than on `api.fetchSomeEntity()`.

Comment: Thank you David. Would you be so kind as to elaborate why using side-effects in the pipeline is considered a bad practice? Because I see sink as something you'd use at the very end of the pipeline (like in a view-model) and it does make sense to attach the save-to-repo job to the use case that fetches the data, not the view-model that is to use the data. I imagine it would make even more sense when the same use case is to be used in multiple view-models.

Comment: @Vahid Combine is a __functional__ reactive programming framework and in functional reactive programming, all functions should be pure functions (so they should have no side effects). If you want to do something like data caching in the middle of your pipeline, the way to do it is to break your pipeline. Check my updating answer on a more detailed example on how to do that

Comment: Well, as I said, I think this is pure opinion, and I don't agree. RxSwift has side effects operators and no one goes into a religious conniption about it. I think the use case at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62139342/performing-side-effects-on-publisher is perfectly legitimate and `handleEvents` is a valid equivalent.